# Unable to Login into my flutter app after updating

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I just made a flutter version of my native android app,After that i published it on my playstore. But there was a problem in login.When New user install app it is working fine but when existing users update current app(native android) to new app (flutter) from playstore. They are unable to login into app.
I am using firebase phone authentication.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's the Play Store Signing Key SHA1 missing.  Get from Release Management -> App Signing, add to the app SHA list in Firebase.

Not documented anywhere I can see - I hit the same thing.  :-P